# Get dynamic value every value of td of tr jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

```
$("#student").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    tr = $('<tr/>');
    tr.append("<td id='id'>" + "<a class=\"school_id\"  id=" + data[i].id + " href='#' value='" + data[i].id + "'>" + data[i].id + "</a>" + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td id='lastname'>" + data[i].lastname + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td id='firstname'>" + data[i].firstname + "</td>");
    //$("#td_id").attr('width', '15%');
    //$('tr td:nth-child(1)').get(0).style.width = '100px';
    //tr.find('td:nth-child(2)').width('30%');‌​
    $("#student").append(tr);
}
```

I have a code here that populates a table with student name.It dynamically gets it data from ajax request from database. I want to know how to get each value of the `td` just by clicking the class `school_id`. I want to get each value and be able to put it in input text box. The end result will be like this after clickng the id

```
var id = $('#tdwithidid').text();
var lastname = $('#tdwithidlastname').text();
var firstname = $('#tdwithidfirstname').text();

$('#id').val(id);
$('#lastname').val(lastname);
$('#firstname').val(firstname);
```

Comment: are you familiar with .parent() and related functions in jQuery?

Comment: how can i use this function to get every data in td in every row and tell which `lastname` and `firstname` belong to which `school id`

Comment: you can add a click function with .each()  to those classes and use the .parent() in conjunction to get that value.

Comment: can you show sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', '#tableid tr', function(e) {
        var id = $(this).find('td:nth-child(1)').text();
        var lastname = $(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
        var firstname = $(this).find('td:nth-child(3)').text();

        $('#id').val(id);
        $('#lastname').val(lastname);
        $('#firstname').val(firstname);
        console.log(tin + lastname + firstname);
    });
```

This will do what you want

Comment: The anchor element should trigger the event based on description, not the row.

Comment: what do you suggest then?i thought i need to put it on the row in order to get all the data in that row if anchor should trigger the event how would you get the value of the data in the same row..please enlighten me as well

Answer (score 1):

Since you are adding the table dynamically you 'll need something like this

```
$('#student').on('click', '. school_id', function(e) {
    var parent = $(e.target).closest('tr'); //gets the parent tr element
    var id = parent.find('#id').html(); //finds element inside specific parent that has an id of id
    var lastName = parent.find('#lastname').html(); //finds element inside specific parent that has an id of last name
    var firstName = parent.find('#firstname').html(); //finds element inside specific parent that has an id of first name
});
```

Comment: sir i want to ask about class `school_id` it is a class of the anchor the value of the first td do i need to put it somewhere else because now i am getting empty console log using this code

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('.school_id').click(function (event){
    var theTd = jQuery(this).parent();
    var theId = theTd.attr('id');
});
```

Something like this?